# Parse key containing unicode characters in JSON with Go

Tags: json, go

I have an API response like this:

```json
{ 
  "Pass ✔": true
}
```

In Go I use this code:

```golang
type Status struct {
  Pass bool `json:"Pass ✔"`
}

// ...

var s Status

json.Unmarshal(body, &s)

fmt.Println(s.Pass) // false, where it should be true
```

How can I correctly unmarshal this JSON document?

Comment: Even correcting the structure of the document so that it *is* valid JSON, I cannot get Go to parse `Pass ✔` into the `Status` struct correctly.

Comment: @LJC I've simplified your JSON document and the code that attempts to consume it, to better focus on the specific issue of the `Pass` field.  Please let me know if this conflicts with your intent.

Comment: The problem is on [this line](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/fca46d0b36c10250713ec0f4c9bf13d626f358d1/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L983).

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, it's not currently possible to do that. As a workaround, you could do something like this:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

type status map[string]bool

func (s status) pass() bool {
   return s["Pass ✔"]
}

func main() {
   data := []byte(`{"Pass ✔": true}`)
   var stat status
   json.Unmarshal(data, &stat)
   pass := stat.pass()
   fmt.Println(pass) // true
}
```